# What is the name for the symbols next to subtitles, commentaries, dolby, etc?

Tags: terminology

[Some square like symbols similar to the ones discussed in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48471/how-to-generate-the-movie-dvd-available-sound-systems-symbols):

[image: example of 5.1 surround sound image]

These appear on the back of physical media, for example DVDs, with various number of little solid squares indicating how many channels of audio are included.

Any hints on what they are called? googling "movie, symbol, subtitle, dolby" etc. brings up completly irrelevant results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are referring to the [*sound mode icon*](https://www.surething.com/ST/Category.asp?CatCode=SE_DESIGNCTR05).

An example:

[image]